# How to split string using regular expressed at every number

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to alter the input of a calculator program to remove all white space and correct the formatting.

If the formatting is as follows:

`2 + 3 * ( 2 + 2 )`

I take this value, split it at every space into an array, turn every number into a float, then my program can recursively solve the problem while conforming to PEMDAS. However, if a user was to come along and whack this in:

`2+3*(2+2)`

it will break loose. I can split it at every number, then what if the user puts

`22+33*(22+22)`

It breaks.

So my idea was to remove any white space and then use a regex to find all the numbers, operators, braces etc., and split them into an array like before.

My desired outcome is:

`["2.0", "+", "3.0", "*", "(", "2.0", "+", "2.0", ")"]`

I have the folowing, which does not work

`better_format = ss.scan(/\d*\.\d*|\+|\-|\*|\%\/|\(\)/)
=> ["2.0", "+", "3.0", "*", "", "2.0", "+", "2.0", "", ""]`

I need some input. To my understanding, my expression is searching for

- Any number of digits, followed by a single period, followed by any number of digits
- Any of the following characters '+, -, *, /, %, (, )'

Comment: `.scan(/\d*\.?\d+|[-+\/*%()]/)`?

Comment: That works, could you break it down in an answer for me?
EDIT: Actually it's pretty easy to understand...lol

Comment: It just does not convert the numbers to float type, keeping them as strings.

Comment: It can convert? Right now I just iterate over it afterwards and cast everything from string, to float, to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s.scan(/\d*\.?\d+|[-+\/*%()]/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ayQRU/1).

Or, to match any type of non-whitespace besides numbers:

```
s.scan(/\d*\.?\d+|[^\d\s]/)
                  ^^^^^^^
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/Ye1O2p).

**Details**

- `\d*\.?\d+` -  0 or more digits, an optional `.` and then 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `[-+\/*%()]` - a `-`, `+`, `/`, `*`, `%`, `(` or `)`
- `[^\d\s]` - any char but whitespace and digit

Comment: FYI for those who saw [my IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Ye1O2p): the `.inspect` is there only for demo purposes, to display the results nicely on that page.

Comment: Not only is this answer correct and informative, I did not know of that regex demo website, very good resources. Thank you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `#to_s` would also work instead of `#inspect`. Or alternatively use `#p` instead of `#puts`.

Comment: @Johan Thanks.  I will edit the demo then once I'm back at the PC

Answer (score 1):

## Integers

Instead of filtering out what you want using [`#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-scan) you could also filter out what you don't want using [`#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-split).

```
'2 + 3 * ( 2 + 2 )'.split(/\s+|\b|(?=\W)/)
#=> ["2", "+", "3", "*", "(", "2", "+", "2", ")"]

'22+33*(22+22)'.split(/\s+|\b|(?=\W)/)
#=> ["22", "+", "33", "*", "(", "22", "+", "22", ")"]
```

This regex splits on:

- Whitespace (`\s+`) when for example `22 +` is given.
- Word boundary (`\b`) when for example `22+` is given.
- A character followed by a non-word character (`(?=\W)`) when for example `*(` is given.

## Floats

The above works for integers, but not for floats. To correctly parse floats we need to write `\b` ourself. `\b` is equal to `(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w)`, thus making heavy usage of [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). If we apply this for only decimals and dots this would result in `(?<=[\d.])(?![\d.])|(?<![\d.])(?=[\d.])`.

Resulting in the following regex:

```
float_boundary = /(?<=[\d.])(?![\d.])|(?<![\d.])(?=[\d.])/
non_float_boundary = /(?<![\d.])(?![\d.])/
regex = /\s+|#{float_boundary}|#{non_float_boundary}/

'22.22+33*(22.34+22.1)'.split(/\s+|\b|(?=\W)/)
#=> ["22", ".", "22", "+", "33", "*", "(", "22", ".", "34", "+", "22", ".", "1", ")"]

'22.22+33*(22.34+22.1)'.split(regex)
#=> ["22.22", "+", "33", "*", "(", "22.34", "+", "22.1", ")"]
```

Comment: I like your approach but note that the OP wishes to permit representations of floats as well, and possibly of negative numbers also.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Completely correct. I've updated the answer to also match floats. It now only has problem differentiating negative numbers from the minus operator. Other answers don't address this and I won't since the regex would get pretty complicated.

Comment: For the case where there are only integers I believe you could write `str.delete(' ').split(/\b/)`.

Comment: That would leave `*(` grouped.

Comment: I just said I believed that, not that it was true.

Answer (score 0):

```
R = /
    (?:       # begin a non-capture group
      (?<=    # begin a positive lookbehind
        \d    # match a digit
        [ ]?  # optionally match a space
      )       # end positive lookbehind
      -       # match a minus sign
    )         # end non-capture group
    |         # or
    -?        # optionally match a minus sign
    \d+       # match one or more digits           
    (?:       # begin a non-capture group
      \.      # match a period 
      \d+     # match one or more digits
    )         # end non-capture group
    ?         # optionally match non-capture group above
    |         # or
    \S        # match a non-whitespace character
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode

def doit(str)
  str.scan(R)
end
```

```
doit "2 + 3 * ( 2 + 2 )"
  #=> ["2", "+", "3", "*", "(", "2", "+", "2", ")"] 
doit "2+3*(2+2)"
  #=> ["2", "+", "3", "*", "(", "2", "+", "2", ")"] 
doit "22+33*(22+22)"
  #=> ["22", "+", "33", "*", "(", "22", "+", "22", ")"] 
doit "(22+33)!*(22-12)"
  #=> ["(", "22", "+", "33", ")", "!", "*", "(", "22",
  #    "-", "12", ")"] 
doit "(22-33)*(22/-12)"
  #=> ["(", "22", "-", "33", ")", "*", "(", "22", "/",
  #    "-12", ")"] 
doit "(22+33.4)*(22/-12.3)"
  #=> ["(", "22", "+", "33.4", ")", "*", "(", "22", "/",
  #    "-12.3", ")"] 
doit "2-1"
  #=> ["2", "-", "1"] 
doit ".2"
  #=> [".", "2"]
```

The regular expression is conventionally written as follows.

```
/(?:(?<=\d )-)|-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\S/
```

Note that the space in the regular expression must be protected in a character class (`[ ]`) when free-spacing mode is used, as spaces as stripped out before the expression is evaluated.

Comment: Pretty nice, but "fails" on `'2-1'.scan(/(?:-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|\S/) #=> ["2", "-1"]`

Comment: @Johan, my flawed logic is "pretty nice"? Hmm. I (think I) fixed it, but I may have just put a finger in a leaking dike. Now I'm off to look at the edit of your answer...